# I oversleep and latest time for shajrit is over.

Tags: arriving-late

I oversleep and latest time for shajrit is over.

What should I do?

Comment: Get an alarm clock for tomorrow!

Comment: May I suggest rewording the question to make it impersonal and more specific. "If somebody due to forces out of his control (the aliens abducted him, whatever, make up your own scenario) was unable to daven shachris before Zman tefillah has passed and then is able to before chatzos. Is there anything for him to do as far as davening shachris other then 2 shemoneh esreis by mincha?"

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!