# Late davening for shacharit

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer, tashlumin

If somebody, due to forces out of his control, was unable to daven shachris before Zman tefillah has passed and then is able to do so before chatzos, is there anything for him to do as far as davening shachris other then 2 shemoneh esreis by mincha?

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86927/i-oversleep-and-latest-time-for-shajrit-is-over

Answer (score 5):

According to Shulchan Aruch ([OC 89:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x455)) one who did not *daven shacharis* until after the time for *shacharis* (four [*halachic* hours](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/526872/jewish/Hours.htm)) and *davens* after that time, until midday, still gets the reward for praying (although not for praying in its time). *Rema* adds that it is forbidden to *daven shacharis* after midday. Taz (ibid. 1) disagrees and says one may *daven shacharis* until the time for *mincha* (approximately half an hour after midday), and still gets the reward for praying.

If one did not *daven shacharis* due to error or [*oness*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3491/9643), he may *daven* the following *mincha* twice, the first for *mincha* and the second as [compensation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/tashlumin/info) for *shacharis* (Shulchan Aruch [OC 108:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x473)).

If he intentionally missed *shacharis*, he cannot *daven mincha* twice as compensation, however, he can *daven* as a voluntary prayer, provided he adds an additional prayer to it (if he does this immediately after the following *mincha* he need not add anything) (ibid. 7).